# MySQL Temp Tables or View?

Tags: mysql, view, temp-tables

I got 3 tables that have stored common data from registration from users: **languages, countries, nationalities**. Each table have fields: **id** and **name**.

I got a main table **users** where it stores almost all the data from the users.

Another table called **tableregistry** which it has this structure:

```
id | tableName | tableValue

 1 | finalJoin | 0

 2 | language  | 1

 3 | country   | 2

 4 |nationality| 3
```

And one more that it stores called **coincidences** the common data that share many of the users:

```
id | idUser | nTable | cValue
```

So if we have the 80th user taht live in Netherlands but he's native from Peru and speak Chinesse the data would save in this way (considering Netherlands have the id 20 in the **country** table, the peruvian nationality have id 34 in the **nationality** table and the chinese language have the id 22 on the **language** table)

```
198 | 80    | 2      | 20

199 | 80    | 3      | 34

200 | 80    | 1      | 22
```

So if we want to perform a search of persons i use a stored procedure to search on **coincidences** the common data just getting 3 temporary tables to get users 1.from certain country 2.taht live on any country than not be the native and 3.speak a certain language.

Doing a multiple join for these temporary tables with the table **users** we would get a list of users for this search.

The question is. Would be better use a view or just keep the temporary table strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a weird schema. How about this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE languages (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

CREATE TABLE countries (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

CREATE TABLE nationalities (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

CREATE TABLE user_rel_languages (
  user_id int(11) not null,
  language_id int(11) not null
);

CREATE TABLE user_rel_countries (
  user_id int(11) not null,
  country_id int(11) not null
);

CREATE TABLE user_rel_nationalities (
  user_id int(11) not null,
  nationality_id int(11) not null
);
```

So to get a user with a specific configuration of language + country + nationality, you would would select from `users` and join with each of those tables through the relation-table. E.g.:

```
select u.* from users u
join user_rel_countries urc on urc.user_id = u.id 
join user_rel_languages url on url.user_id = u.id 
join user_rel_nationalities urn on urn.user_id = u.id 
where country_id = 1 and language_id = 2 and nationality_id = 3 
group by u.id ;
```

Or if you don't care about the denormalisation, you could drop the distinction between `countries` and `user_rel_countries`

Comment: Ok that's a standard schema, it's totally ok but how about the performance if we're talking about thousands of records. And the worse scenario... how about if the commondata entities grow up. So do I have to create more tables for each new entity and the respective relation userid_entity?.
Sorry if I sound kinda annoying but I'm trying to get the best performance for this project

Comment: If they are different types, then yes - I would create a separate table for each. The performance of this should scale quite well as long as you put an index on the key columns.

Comment: You mean put index on the nationality_id, country_id and language_id columns on the user_rel_* tables?

Comment: Both. The rel tables are special in that they have a combined primary key and each of these columns are foreign keys. So they would each have 3 indexes defined.

Comment: ok composite primary key on rel tables to give integrity. But foreign keys? i thought you're working on MyISAM

Comment: InnoDB has support for foreign key constraints, but even if you use MyISAM, you can still define an index on the columns. Whether the database supports it or not, they are conceptually foreign keys.

Comment: Oooh yes, actually I was thinking "maybe he's trying to apply the fk  conceptually", but as you mentioned it I thought about to set it. And now that I've changed the model it's working and the coding process it's much more easy. Thank you for you help I appreciate it too much!!!